# Grid stack items when I validate a form without changing the values

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

Why when I open my form through a window and I change nothing and I agree, my grid item stacks instead of recharged my grid? but I change the values ​​of my form and I agree, my grid is reloaded correctly?

Thanx in advance

EDIT : Store.sync returns an error if you do not change the data

[The picture of the bug](http://corto.vv.si/gridbug.jpg)

My code:

```
var modele = Modeles[activeTabParametresApplicatifs]; // Ex: Name
var id = 'Id'+modele; // IdName
var chaine = activeTabParametresApplicatifs; // TabNames
var store = chaine.substr(3,chaine.length); // Names

eval ('record = Ext.create(\'ModuleGestion.model.'+modele+'\');');
eval ('store = this.get'+store+'Store()');

var win    = button.up('window'),
    form   = win.down('form');
record = form.getRecord();
values = form.getValues();

eval ('var id = values.'+id);



if (form.isValid()) {

    if (id > 0){
        record.set(values);

    } else{
        record.set(values);
        store.add(record);

    }

    store.sync({
        success : function() {
            store.load();
        }
    });

    win.close();

}
```

Comment: Stop using eval like that, there's no need.
`var id = values[id];`

Answer (score 0):

Dude! Following your code is like tracking a Bigfoot! Why all those pointless evals?

Start by replacing that:

```
eval ('var id = values.'+id);
```

With that:

```
id = values.id;
```

Then remove all the other evals, and quit the habit of using them **now**.

Ok, sorry for this outburst but you were really going down a very dangerous road. So, regarding your question, just a wild guess considering the lack of context, but couldn't the culprit be this line:

```
store.add(record);
```

Comment: And does the problem persist if you remove it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I won't be able to help much more. In part because I don't understand what you want to say. You know, if you don't master English language, you should just post a working and **complete** code example (like we can copy-paste and run it), and concentrate on saying (1) what you want (2) what you get instead. I'm sure you would get useful answers this way.

Comment: if i delete store.add, it's equal same bug

Comment: ...entre lyonnais on devrait ce comprendre pourtant ahaha